# Is correct this update state in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Input event

```
   public handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        this.setState({ emptyFields: false, error: false, loading: false });
        this.setState({ product: { ...this.state.product, [e.target.name]: e.target.value } });
    }
```

Map test

```
 <tbody>
    {this.props.products.map((prod: IProduct) =>{
     console.log('remap ???')
    return (<tr key={prod.id}>
     <td>{prod.id}</td>
     <td>{prod.name}</td>
     <td>{prod.price}</td>
    </tr>)
    }                            
   )}
 </tbody>
```

When I change the input, this map is made again as many times as I change the input.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you change the state, react will call the render method again.This is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Break out parts of your html in seperate components and make the components pure. This will prevent needless re render of DOM. However; at the moment it won't re render dom because virtual DOM compare of React will optimize. You will get in trouble if each row gets props that are recreated every time the parent renders, like not using useCallback for the delete callback:

```js
//use React.memo to create a pure component
const ProductRow = React.memo(function ProductRow({
  product: { id, name },
  onDelete,
}) {
  console.log('generating jsx for product:', id);
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{id}</td>
      <td>{name}</td>
      <td>
        <button onClick={() => onDelete(id)}>X</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
});
//React.memo is pure component, only re renders if
//  props (=products or onDelete) change
const Products = React.memo(function Products({
  products,
  onDelete,
}) {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>name</th>
        </tr>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <ProductRow
            key={product.id}
            product={product}
            onDelete={onDelete}
          />
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
});
const id = ((id) => () => ++id)(0); //create id
const AddProduct = React.memo(function AddProduct({
  onAdd,
}) {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  //no use to use useCallback, this function re creates
  //  when name changes
  const save = () => {
    onAdd(name);
    setName('');
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        name:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <button onClick={save}>save</button>
    </div>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  //initial products state
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState(() => [
    { id: id(), name: 'first product' },
    { id: id(), name: 'second product' },
  ]);
  //use useCallback to create an add function on mount
  //  this function is not re created causing no needless
  //  re renders for AddProduct
  const onAdd = React.useCallback(
    (name) =>
      setProducts((products) =>
        products.concat({
          id: id(),
          name,
        })
      ),
    []
  );
  //delete function only created on mount
  const onDelete = React.useCallback(
    (id) =>
      setProducts((products) =>
        products.filter((product) => product.id !== id)
      ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <AddProduct onAdd={onAdd} />
      <Products products={products} onDelete={onDelete} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```